# gmaps4rails trigger side bar click event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails sidebar function to allow jumping to individual marker on the map.

My question is:

how can I trigger the click event on the first sidebar item so the 1st marker's info window will be display by default?

Answer (score 1):

You should just add a callback:

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
  var firstMarker = Gmaps.map.markers[0];
  var map         = Gmaps.map.map;
  firstMarker.infowindow.open(map, firstMarker.serviceObject);
}
```

Be sure to put this callback after the `gmaps` helper in your view.